# Json.parse error with inverted comma

Tags: php, json, string, parsing

I am handling questions and answers(stored somewhere) in my forum using JSON.parse() function.
For a response like

```
response = {"Q":"What is PHP","reply":"Google it"}
```

it works fine but in case user input something with inverted commas I face problems 
e.g.

```
response = {"Q":"What is PHP","reply":"Google **"what is php"**"}
```

How would i escape those inverted commas?

Comment: I guess you mean *quotation marks* with "inverted commas"? Btw, if the response really is `{"Q":"What is PHP","reply":"Google "what is php""}` then you have invalid JSON. If you create valid JSON from he start, then you won't have a problem. That means you should use the methods provided by the language to generate JSON (e.g. `json_encode`) and not create it "manually".

Comment: Thanks Felix, json_encode solved my problem. I was creating JSON manually so I was unable to escape the quotation marks automatically...

Answer (score 2):

Prefix any embedded double-quotes with a backslash:

```
response = {"Q":"What is PHP","reply":"Google \"what is php\""}
```

Answer (score 1):

from javascript use `encodeUriComponent` from php use `urlencode`

Answer (score 0):

Escape it

```
response = {"Q":"What is PHP","reply":"Google **\"what is php\"**"}
```